# Return same implementation of List as passed in parameter

Tags: java, class, interface-implementation

Let's say I have a function similar to the following:

```
public static List<Integer> empty(List<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> empty = new ArrayList<>();
    return empty;
}
```

which I want to return a List of the same implementation as the passed in list. For my example function, this is only true if the passed in list is an ArrayList. How do I initialize a List based on the implemenation of `list` (e.g. so the returned List would be a LinkedList if `list` was a LinkedList)?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: In general, you can't do this. The type of `list` may not be accessible or have an accessible constructor (although you could change it using reflection, provided there isn't a security manager that will block you). Or the only constructor(s) may require arguments that your code is unable to supply. `list` may even be something weird like an instance of a private inner class of an abstract containing class, bound to an instance of the containing class.

Comment: I was just curious if this was possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you need this. For me, it is a bad design. However, you can do it using `reflection`:

```
public static List<Integer> empty(List<Integer> list) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<? extends List> c = list.getClass();
    return c.newInstance();
}
```

Note: above example only works if `List` implementation class have a public accessible empty constructor else you will get an exception.

Comment: Will fail for `empty(Arrays.asList(5))`.

Comment: Will also fail if the method parameter is null ;-)

Comment: Point is: there is no general way to do this.

Comment: Yes, there may be few more corner cases which need to be handled. My idea was to give a clue/ way so that OP can progress further.